# Running a flask application of server

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application, and when I run it after copying the files to the server the usual message is displayed,

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
* Restarting with reloader
```

But when I go to my server's ip address(port 5000), ie http://162.XXX.XXX.XX:5000, I see nothing there.

Where does the server deploy the flask application ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the solution, instead of app.run() in the last line, changed that to app.run(host='0.0.0.0'), which basically tells flask to listen to all public IP's

[Source](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/)

Comment: This Q&A is really useful for containerized versions of Flask as it can be an overlook. The local machine for your Flask app is not really YOUR local machine.